# Port forwarding on Spinnaker

Tags: browser, ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel, spinnaker

I am doing a port forwarding to connect my local machine to Spinnaker.

Step1: -> Localhost to AWS instance

```
ssh -A -L 9000:localhost:9000 -L 8084:localhost:8084 -L 8087:localhost:8087 ec2-user@<aws-instance-ip>
```

Step2: -> Aws instance to Spinnaker cluster

```
ssh -L 9000:localhost:9000 -L 8084:localhost:8084 -L 8087:localhost:8087 ubuntu@10.100.10.5
```

This works fine when i do `http://localhost:9000`

However, instead of port forwarding from local machine I want to setup a tunnel from another aws instance (Eg: 55.55.55.55) and access via `http://55.55.55.55:9000` . So that other team members can i directly access Spinnaker UI.

I have tried following the above steps from 55.55.55.55 host and then tried

```
http://55.55.55.55:9000 however it didnt work.
```

What should i change to make it resolve on 55.55.55.55 host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port forwarding is bound to the IP you give to ssh. If you give localhost (default), it will be accessible only on localhost (`127.0.0.1`). If you want to access it from outside, you need to give the `55.55.55.55` address instead.

You will also need a `-g` switch to `ssh`, which will allow remote hosts to connect to your locally forwarded ports.